# Dictionary is not being added to

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dictionary using keys and values from other dictionaries. The issue I'm having is that the dictionary I want to return comes up empty.

Note:

```
USER_RATING_DICT_SMALL = {1: {68735: 3.5, 302156: 4.0}, 2: {68735: 1.0, 124057: 1.5, 293660: 4.5}}
MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL = {293660: [2], 68735: [1, 2], 302156: [1], 124057: [2]}
```

```py
def movies_to_users(user_ratings):
    """Return a dictionary of movie ids to list of users who rated the movie,
    using information from the user_ratings dictionary of users to movie
    ratings dictionaries.

    >>> result = movies_to_users(USER_RATING_DICT_SMALL)
    >>> result == MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL
    True
    """
    user_list = []
    movie_to_users = {}
    for items in user_ratings.items():
        user_id = items[0]
        user_list.append(user_id)

    for items in user_ratings.items():
        movie_id = items[1]
        if movie_id in user_list:
            movie_to_users[movie_id] = [user_list]

    return movie_to_users
```

I created an empty dictionary for all the values and keys to accumulate to but it is not accumulating; it returns an empty dictionary instead. I want the output to be == MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL

Comment: I'm unclear on the logic of your loops. Why would any of the values of `USER_RATING_DICT_SMALL`, which are dicts, ever be contained within the list of keys, which are integers?

Comment: Your first loop will get `user_list = [1,2]`. The second loop looks wrong. `movie_id` will be `{68735: 3.5, 302156: 4.0}` on the first pass which I suspect is not what was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty short solution might be

```py
MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL = {}
for user, data in USER_RATING_DICT_SMALL.items():
    for movie in data.keys():
        if not movie in MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL.keys():
            # add entry for each movie
            # will be an empty list if no user rated.
            MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL[movie] = [] 
        # for user in current iteration, there MUST be a rating...
        # otherwise, movie would not be in data.keys()
        MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL[movie] += [user] 

MOVIE_USER_DICT_SMALL
# {68735: [1, 2], 302156: [1], 124057: [2], 293660: [2]}
```

The trick is to use `key` and `value` as returned by `dict.items()`